# What is best practice to simultaneously manage forks of multiple repos inside a main project?

Tags: git, github, gitlab

I have a project that uses a number of dependencies, which I want to update myself but keep current with fixes in the master branch.

For example, let say I have a basic website:

```
- page.html // my code
   - javacript.js // a fork of a third party project, which I have modified
   - styles.css // another fork of another third party project, again which I have modified
```

**My forks are customised specific for use with my project, to an extent they would not be used elsewhere**

I understand [best practice](https://help.github.com/en/github/getting-started-with-github/fork-a-repo) for a fork is to i) fork the project, ii) add the upstream to the original source, and iii) create a branch to work on so it's easy to compare and manage changes.

However, in the example above I am also using git to manage the overall project and I am cloning the third party forks into the same folder. This means I only have one repo so it all gets merged into one project and I don't see how I can still compare the forks to their source.

If I want to keep all the repos separate, do I need to switch the repo and sync each every time I update, or is there a way to link everything so one push/pull updates all the repos/forks at once?

Answer (score 0):

To me this sounds like you might need to maintain two repositories if you want to be able to contribute to the upstream of the fork you are using.  Perhaps you could use some form of CI/CD to automate your build process in the two repo scenario.

Comment: Can I just nest one repo in another?